# How to set breakpoints at specific spots in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a program that modifies images. When I try to compare the results of my program to the expected values the result is pretty much unreadable.[image]

This continues for very very long, so how can I make it so that I only see the difference between the expected and actual values, and where these differences are?

And when using the inbuild debugger, for example if I have a loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    do stuff
  }
}
```

How can I set up a breakpoint so the debugger can tell me the values of things I need to know to find out what the error is:

1. When i = 99
2. Right before a discrepancy between the expected and actual value occurs
3. Right before the program exits to an error such as out of bounds.

Because currently, all I can do set a breakpoint on a specific line, but inside a loop I have to click step over repeatedly rather than skip to where I need in the loop.

Comment: You can set conditional breakpoint based on specific variable values.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#set-breakpoints

Answer (score -1):

> TLDR; right click on a breakpoint and add code that returns a boolean
> to make it a conditional breakpoint

I think this post useful for your question.

[conditional breakpoint in IntelliJ](https://www.eviltester.com/2016/08/convert-breakpoint-into-conditional.html)